# Nginx client_max_body_size can't more than 2000m

Tags: nginx

I made a cloud storage and yesterday I want to upload a file over 2GB and I tried to change the client_max_body_size to 10G and Nginx is not starting and showed up:

nginx: [emerg] "client_max_body_size" directive invalid value in drive.conf:17

How do I fix this?

Steps to replicate issue above:

1. Set client_max_body_size to more than 2000m or more than 2g
2. Start nginx

Comment: can you paste the string from your config?

Comment: what nginx version are you using? you can check by running `nginx -v`  eg ```$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)```

Comment: perhaps nginx is encountering an invisible/unprintable character? what do you get from ```cat nginx.conf | base64 | nc termbin.com 9999``` ? investigating that is best done in a hex editor, for example [HxD Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)

Answer (score -1):

just want to say, i can *NOT* reproduce this on nginx version 1.18.0:
setting

```
client_max_body_size 2000000000000M;
```

is accepted (this is 2 million terabytes, or ***2 billion gigabytes***)

however

```
client_max_body_size 20000000000000M;
```

is not accepted (this is 20 million terabytes, or 20 billion gigabytes) and i get the

```
nginx: [emerg] "client_max_body_size" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/files1.lan:23
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```